# Shorted battery on 2020 Mercedes A35, now car won't start

Tags: electronic-control-module, mercedes-benz, fuse, no-crank-no-start, a35

I recently had a short happen to me when I was looking at a broken plastic clip on the ECU housing. I was just trying to get the part # to replace it, so I wasn't expecting to work on the car and need to disconnect the battery.

When I rotated the ECU to see the back of the cracked plastic part on it, a piece of the metal enclosing the ECU hit the positive terminal on the battery and caused an arc/short, and now the car won't start. I can get into accessory mode and see the display on the dash (speedometer/tach) and radio screen so I assume the ECU is OK, but no ignition when I hit the starter button. I checked the main fuse box and they're all fine, except for the starter fuses. There's no power going to them, so I thought it was either a linkable fuse blew, or something in the pre-fuse box.

I tested the continuity at various points on the battery, and the points indicated by either ends of the green line in the picture below. They were good (so the pyro fuse is fine), but the one in red was not.

[image]

That leads me to believe that the fuse in the charge sensor (if there is one there) is blown.

I tried to bypass it by attaching jumper cables from the positive terminal to the far end of the pyro fuse as indicated by the blue path in the above linked picture, and also below  but the car still wouldn't start.

[image]

I'm thinking there could be something else keeping the car from starting apart from the possible dead fuse in the charge sensor. I also checked the continuity on the (125A and 80A) high amp pre-fuses coming up the side of the main fuse box pictured below), and they were OK.

[image]

I also tried pulling out the box to the left of the battery with the thick red cables coming out of it pictured below.

[image]

I opened it up to test the continuity on the 3 fuses inside (30A, 300A, 200A, pictured below) and they were OK too.

[image]

At this point I'm at a loss on what else could be keeping the car from starting. Any ideas on what else I could check to see why the car won't start?

Answer (score 3):

I presume that is the ECU in the foreground of the first picture.

You said that the metal case touched directly on the battery positive terminal.

Since the case was not bolted to the chassis at this point, the current from the battery will have passed through the case and down the ground wires running to the ECU via the ECU connector.

It is highly likely that the ground wires in the connector go straight to the ECU PCB and that the case is grounded to the PCB.

This could have cause a ground track in the ECU to burn out due to the large current flowing through it when you shorted it.

I presume the functions you are seeing in the dash do not need the engine ECU to operate.  You could verify this by disconnecting the ECU and seeing if the dash still works.

I would test the continuity of the ECU case to the battery negative.  If there is now no continuity, this would back up my theory.

Do this test and report back.

Comment: OK so I unplugged the ECU and the dash still comes on line before, so it looks like that stuff doesn't need the ECU. Should I check the wires coming to the ECU now to see if they got burned by the current going through them?

Comment: Have you checked continuity between the ECU case and the battery negative terminal?

Comment: I checked and yes, with the battery terminals connected  there is.

Comment: Just to confirm, with the case of the ECU not touching the bodywork at all, you have a very low resistance between the case and the battery negative terminal?  Do you recall how many ohms?

Comment: I went back to check the resistance and it wasn't registering continuity any more, which I thought was odd. I then put the car in accessory mode and then turned it off, and it started registering continuity between the negative terminal and the ECU.
When in continuity mode, the number on the display was -489. I put it in resistance mode (Ω) 20 and the number on the display was -12.1. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: You want everything off to do the test.  I believe the fact that there was initially no continuity backs up my theory that there is damage in the ECU.  It may be repairable, but it is also possible that major damage has been done.

Comment: OK thanks for the response. I'll take it to an ECU repair shop to have them check it out.

Comment: Have you tried connecting an OBD2 reader?  It would be interesting to see if it did anything.

Comment: I'm going to borrow a friend's Autel diagnostic reader this weekend and try reading whatever code there is then. I should have a better idea at that point.

Comment: If the ECU is damaged, then you will likely get no response from it.

Comment: I got a whole bunch of codes because there are many parts that are currently disconnected, but one code that seems to relate to the ECU is U0100 "Lost communication with ECM/PCM".
Would that happen with ECU damage?

Comment: it could also be because I unplugged the ECU at one point

Comment: I would clear all of the codes, then see which ones come back.  Those will be the important ones.

Comment: there are a whole bunch of codes that came back. many relate to currently unplugged parts, but there are a bunch that start with U (e.g. U010000) that relate to communication. The one about losing communication with the ECU didn't come back though, which is a good sign. Maybe that means it's communicating with the ECU now.

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that the battery gets drained when it's connected but the car is off. I'm hearing a high pitched whine when I plug the battery back in. I can't get where it's coming from but it seems like it's deeper within the engine bay. Could there be a blown relay in there somewhere that's causing that? I do hear a click when trying to start the car, so it seems like the car is sending the signal to start, but I'm not sure if it reaches the starter motor.

Comment: Have you got a wiring diagram for the vehicle?

Comment: I don't unfortunately, but I have one on the way. It's being shipped from overseas so I'm not sure when it'll arrive. 
I've also heard a parasitic drain and high pitched sound could be an issue with the alternator. With the car not starting I'm not sure how to test the alternator though.

Comment: Hi Howie. I got the shop manual that has wiring diagrams. How do you think that would help? 
One other thing I did is put a wire to the starter relay and the starter cranked, so I confirmed that the starter is OK. The car wouldn't start though even though the starter was cranking. I also pulled out the aux. battery and it was totally drained. I charged it back to full and stuck it back in but still no dice with the car starting.

Comment: I also found out that the high pitched buzz is coming from the transmission oil pan. I think the pump is trying to run because the oil was low at one point. I put more oil in, but since I can't start the car, I can't run the procedure to check the oil level with a scanner.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was the ECU that was fried. You can see the part with the melted plastic in the picture below, where the current went through the circuit board

[image]